# using $variable inside preg_match function

Tags: php, url-routing

I'm trying to learn MVC with PHP with some online courses. So in this tutorial, the teacher trying to detect a path.

```
$pathCheck=preg_match("@^{$link}$@",'$this->nowPath',$params);

print_r($params);
```

When he opens the project with desired path, let's say **project/index.php**, **Array** returns with **1**.

If he try to write **wrong path** like **project/asdasdas.php** , **Array** returns with **0**.

But for me, it returns empty.

```
Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( )
```

I think the problem is preg_match part `"@^{$link}$@"`

I'm stucked.

I'm working on a localhost. AppServ (PHP Ver 7.3)

**EDİT**:

I'm adding my full codes to explain my situation a little bit better.

**app.php**

```
<?php

class App
{

    protected $nowPath;
    protected $nowMethod;
    protected static $routes = [];

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->nowPath = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        $this->nowMethod = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
        $this->startRoute();

    }

    public static function getAction($link, $path, $auth = false, $area = null)
    {

        self::$routes = ['GET', $link, $path, $auth, $area];

    }

    public function startRoute()
    {
        foreach (self::$routes as $routes) {

            list($method, $link, $path, $auth, $area) = $routes;
            $methodCheck = $this->nowMethod == $method;
            $pathCheck=preg_match("@^{$link}$@",'$this->nowPath',$params);

            print_r($params);


        }
    }



}

?>
```

**route.php**;

```
<?php
App::getAction('/index','/default/index',false); ?>
```

Comment: Would you show us the values of `$link` and `$this->nowPath`

Comment: I'm editing my post with full codes.

Comment: `'$this->nowPath'` with single quotes is wrong, php does not perform any variable replacement in single-quoted strings. Use double-quotes " so that `"$this->nowpath"` will be replaced with the `nowpath` class property value at runtime

Comment: @Pierre, thnks for the advice. I did it but unfortunately problem continues. Also i start to using PHP Storm. Before i was using Sublime Text 3.
Anyway, inside of preg_match function, PHP Storm shows orange color to this to character ^,$.
Here is the screenshot; https://i.hizliresim.com/AOovgp.png
Can the problem happens that part?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed finally. I'm not fully understand but the teacher working with project/index folder.Mine was www/project/index. Maybe i made mistake on routing.